# applyImpulse on SKSpriteNode in touchesBegan not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I'm kinda new to Swift. I have this problem, where the SpriteNode "Ball" is not reacting to applyImpulse command in touchesBegan-method. The overall physicsBody works totally fine, gravity, restitution etc. But nothing is happening, when I use applyImpulse. Here's the code:

```
var ball = SKSpriteNode()

 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -9.81)


    // Add the ball

    ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")
    ball.setScale(2.0)
    ball.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2)
    ball.zPosition = 100.0

    // Physics of the ball
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.frame.size.height / 2)
    ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    ball.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    ball.physicsBody?.mass = 2.0
    ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.8
    ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 5.0)

    self.addChild(ball)

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    self.ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0.0, 5.0))



}
```

Please help me :)

Obviously I have a ground too, this is just the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create local object ball with this line of code:

```
let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")
```

inside `didMoveToView` method. It created and placed to scene with `self.addChild(ball)`. But in this line of code:

```
self.ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0.0, 5.0))
```

you call `physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0.0, 5.0))` from other `ball` object which is not represented in the code that you posted here. And this object is not the same object you created in `didMoveToView` method.

You need to init your global for this function `ball` object in your `didMoveToVeiw`:

```
ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")
```

without `let` keyword

Comment: I don't get it. I've improved my code, but it still doesn't work:

Comment: @CodeCake can you post more code where the `ball` object is defined

Comment: I edited the code (above) like you said, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @CodeCake I add your code to empty project and the `ball` object is fall immediately after creation, if you do not so, then you are not post all your code, and if so then the question is formulated do not end up

Comment: Yes, wait, I will post my ground

Comment: @CodeCake Any way you need to move this line `ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.frame.size.height / 2)` from `didMoveToView` to `touchesBegan` method